# pulling "Create" strings from SQLite3 databases

Tags: android, sqlite, oncreate

Is there a simple way to get the CREATE string from each of your tables in Android instead of redefining them in onCreate override.  I am annoyed enough to just parse the whole thing for each table, but I am hoping there is an easier way I have not found yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in table `sqlite_master`

```
sqlite-3.7.2 e$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.2
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t1 (a, b, c integer);
sqlite> create table t2 (d, e, f text);
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
table|t1|t1|2|CREATE TABLE t1 (a, b, c integer)
table|t2|t2|3|CREATE TABLE t2 (d, e, f text)
sqlite> select sql from sqlite_master;
CREATE TABLE t1 (a, b, c integer)
CREATE TABLE t2 (d, e, f text)
```

See: [SQLite3 FAQ #7](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7)